# Files/Programs on removable HDD

Tags: files

I'm going to install Ubuntu onto my dad's computer that is running Windows XP. He wants all his files and his Microsoft programs (Word, Excel) to be on the computer after Ubuntu is installed. We have moved all the files/programs to an external hard drive. This may be dumb question, but will we be able to move them to the internal hard drive? Or will they be removed?

Answer (score 0):

mmm you cant move programs and expect them to work in a totally different OS unless it is the .exe installer (still not all executable programs will install easy like in windows, many even would NOT RUN/WORK AT ALL). Now if is Office package what your dad needs then you can do that no problem, there are plenty of tutorials out there but you need to have the executable file, the cd or the .iso with the installer (Though Ubuntu comes with LIBRE OFFICE but i understand why you would keep office for your dad)

About your dad's files sure can be copied back to the pc after ubuntu install, while they are all backed up in a external hdd you'll be safe. IF your dad doesn't have plenty of files like to almost fill your disk then what i would recommend is to repartition the XP pc, in the new LARGE partition (say disk D: labeled FILES) move all the files to that partition, so when your going to install Ubuntu you do it on Disk C: which contains the windows XP the the other partition "Disk D:" will be like if nothing happened because you didn't touch that partition and so you can share and access those files with ease.

Just go with what it's easier for you.

Answer (score 0):

Of course Ubuntu accepts simple file transfer within drives. You have to give us more specifications of your system and HDD used.

Important: read these.

If you're on a dual boot: then you should've installed Ubuntu on a separate drive (like F drive, D drive, etc. - the Windows is automatically installed in the C drive - if you let it be intact, all information will stay as it is so that it's accessible when you boot the Windows system).

If you're **removing** Windows and **then** installing Ubuntu, then there's no use of those programs, as they won't be accessible.

As alternatives, Ubuntu comes packed with LibreOffice suite, that's pretty much same to the Microsoft Office suite and includes the rich text editor (like Word), the spreadsheet editor (like Excel), advanced paint program (like MS Paint - this one can also open files like PDFs and .cdr), presentation (like PowerPoint).